Facebook Leadgen Webhook Returning Mock Data Instead of Real Leads
I'm developing an application to capture leads from a Facebook lead form. Here's what I've done so far:

I created an App in the Facebook Developer Dashboard.
I verified the webhook for this app, and the verification was
successful.
I have obtained advanced access for the following permissions:
leads_retrieval,
pages_show_list,
pages_manage_metadata.
I have enabled the User object and subscribed to leadgen events.
I tested the webhook, and it's sending test leads in the response as
expected.
My app is in Live mode.

However, when a real lead is created on Facebook, I'm receiving the following response instead of the actual lead data:
{
  "entry": [
    {
      "id": "0",
      "time": 1724921046,
      "changes": [
        {
          "field": "leadgen",
          "value": {
            "ad_id": "444444444",
            "form_id": "444444444444",
            "leadgen_id": "444444444444",
            "created_time": 1724921046,
            "page_id": "444444444444",
            "adgroup_id": "44444444444"
          }
        }
      ]
    }
  ],
  "object": "page"
}

What could I be doing wrong, and how can I start receiving real lead data instead of this mock response?
this is screen shot of my app:-
App details:-

Permission Details:-

Webhook Details:-

